# Setting ACL for a temporarily mounted directory

Tags: linux, mount, acl

I wanted to set ACL for a directory. For that it is important that the device should be mounted as `acl` on that directory.

But I do not want to add the `acl` mount in `/etc/fstab`. So I am tempoararily mounting the device to some temporary directory as `acl` and setting ACL and then unmounting it. Then, I'm mounting it to the original directory.

The code is below:

```
tmp="/tmp1/backup"
orig="/mnt1/backup"
dev="/dev/sda2"

mkdir -p $tmp
mkdir -p $orig
mount -o acl $dev $tmp
mkdir -p $tmp/stdsymp
chgrp 557 $tmp/stdsymp
setfacl -m g:599:r $tmp/stdsymp
umount $tmp

mount $dev $orig
```

`ll  /mnt/backup` shows

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root _nokfsuimanage  4096 Sep  8 09:37 stdsymp
```

The group is being changed, but ACL is not set for the directory. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the `acl` option, it turns off *all* ACL-related operations – not just setting, but also testing and even *reading* ACLs. You *will* have to mount with `acl` in order for your changes to be visible.

If you for some *curious* reason do not want to edit fstab, you can enable the option in the superblock with `tune2fs -o acl $dev`, and it will be applied anywhere the disk is mounted. (This is limited to ext[234] filesystems, however.)

FYI, you do not need to mount/unmount/mount – you can reconfigure a mounted filesystem with `mount -o remount,acl /mnt1/backup`.